# Creating a .jar file which includes package folder

Tags: java, executable-jar

What I want to do is create a `.jar` file, the folder has a `myprogram.class` in it and a package folder, in this package folder is all the other `.class` files.

In the myprogram.class file there is no main method, only a run method which runs the program. I've tried

```
jar cfe myJar.jar myProgram myProgram.class
```

Then when I try to execute it with

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

nothing happens. I decided to extract the `.jar` file and noticed that it wasn't including the package folders `.class` files only the myprogram.class file, can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong, or provide a solution.

Comment: Unclear. But anyway, if you have no main method in a class, then that class can't be the main class of a jar file. You need a main method. Java looks for one. It don't care about your run method.

Comment: why did people down vote this question. If you down vote, maybe provide a reason please. It seems people only down vote to improve there own rep, its really annoying. I'm sure everyone gets stuck at times, if you don't like the question or want to reply, move on, let it go. I see it all the time.

Comment: Just fyi, downvoting a question doesn't improve the rep of the voter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a JAR file with `java -jar`, it needs:

1. A class containing a `public static void main(String[])` method.
2. A META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file that names that class in its `Main-class:` attribute.

It doesn't appear that you've satisfied either criterion.

Package folders have nothing to do with it.